# Library Routing in Angular 14 with Standalone Components

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 14 and their new Standalone Components feature **in the context of a library**.
How can I use RouterModule.forChild() in the component as Angular won't let me do it?

```
...
projects/
  my-lib/
    src/lib
      root.component.ts
  my-app/
...
```

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild([])],
  selector: 'my-lib-root',
  template: ` <router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
export class RootComponent {}
```

Got the error

```
'imports' contains a ModuleWithProviders value, likely the result of a 'Module.forRoot()'-style call. These calls are not used to configure components and are not valid in standalone component imports - consider importing them in the application bootstrap instead.
```

But as I'm using a library, I don't have any "application bootstrap" in this context.

Comment: Why do you need to import `RouterModule`? I think the error message is very clear in what it says - it's not possible to do this in standalone components.

Comment: Because my lib needs some routing. It's not a single component. Okay then I guess this is a limitation and for that scenario I have to use good old NgModule?

Comment: It appears to be, but it also makes sense for standalone components (and libraries) to not influence routing (and the url), which is why i asked about it.

Comment: There are other use cases for this question, not only routing. Using a library whose main module requires forChild Configuration is the first one coming to my mind, think about `ngx-translate`, so if we need to move back to @NgModule based components to allow this, as only solution, this should be marked as an issue in the @angular source. At least for `@angular/cli@15` the problem persists

Answer (score 4):

If you need all, or multiple RouterModule directives in your standalone component, you can import them all by importing the whole RouterModule.

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  ...
})
export class MyAwesomeComponent {}
```

The preferred way would be **importing only the directives you will actually use**. For example, if you plan to use 'router-outlet' from RouterModule, you can just import RouterOutlet.

The same applies for all the other components, directives, or whole modules.

```
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet],
  ...
})
export class MyAwesomeComponent {}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just drop the .forChild([]). You don't want a "ModuleWithProviders" at your component level.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, since version 14.2

You can use routing like this:

```
export const TEST_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'test1',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: TestComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'test1',
        loadComponent: () =>
          import('../test1/test1.component').then((m) => m.Test1Component),
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

then

```
export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'test',
  },
  {
    path: 'test',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./app/test/test.routes').then((m) => m.TEST_ROUTES),
  },
];
```